# Retrieve 1st Degree Connections and 2nd Degree Connections for All Nodes in Igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, sna

I have an igraph where I would like to extract all of the 1st degree connections of each node along with the 2nd degree connections. The tables need to be separate though.

Full reproducible code with picture of graph is below:

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
B = matrix( 
  c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
  nrow=10, 
  ncol=10)
colnames(B) <- c("Alpha", "Bravo", "Colonel", "Demo", "Egg", "Felix", "Gasoline", "Hurricane", "Indigo", "Jab")
rownames(B) <- c("Alpha", "Bravo", "Colonel", "Demo", "Egg", "Felix", "Gasoline", "Hurricane", "Indigo", "Jab")

g96e = t(B) %*% B

i96e = graph.adjacency(g96e, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag=FALSE)
visIgraph(i96e)
```

[image]

I would like my final result to be a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Node ID     1st Degree Connections
Alpha           Gasoline
Bravo           Egg
Bravo           Hurricane
Colonel         Felix
Colonel         Indigo
Demo            Felix
Demo            Gasoline
Demo            Jab
Egg             Bravo
Felix           Colonel
Felix           Demo
Felix           Hurricane
Felix           Indigo
Gasoline        Alpha
Gasoline        Demo
Gasoline        Jab
Hurricane       Bravo
Hurricane       Felix
Indigo          Colonel
Indigo          Felix
Jab             Demo
Jab             Gasoline
```

And then another dataframe with just 2nd degree connections and ideally showing where the source of the 2nd degree connection from but if that's not possible then just the 2nd degree connection would do.

```
Node ID     2nd Degree Connections        From 1st Degree Connection
Alpha               Demo                     Gasoline
Alpha               Jab                      Gasoline
Bravo               Felix                    Hurricane
Colonel             Demo                     Felix
Colonel             Hurricane                Felix
Colonel             Indigo                   Felix
Colonel             Felix                    Indigo
Demo                Colonel                  Felix
Demo                Hurricane                Felix
Demo                Indigo                   Felix
Demo                Alpha                    Gasoline
Demo                Jab                      Gasoline
Demo                Gasoline                 Jab
Egg                 Hurricane                Bravo
Felix               Indigo                   Colonel
Felix               Gasoline                 Demo
Felix               Jab                      Demo
Felix               Bravo                    Hurricane
Felix               Colonel                  Indigo
Gasoline            Felix                    Demo
Gasoline            Jab                      Demo
Gasoline            Demo                     Jab
Hurricane           Egg                      Bravo
Hurricane           Colonel                  Felix
Hurricane           Demo                     Felix
Hurricane           Indigo                   Felix
Indigo              Felix                    Colonel
Indigo              Colonel                  Felix
Indigo              Demo                     Felix
Indigo              Hurricane                Felix
Jab                 Felix                    Demo
Jab                 Gasoline                 Demo
Jab                 Alpha                    Gasoline
Jab                 Demo                     Gasoline
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Degree connection, by definition, is the other vertice connected to the edges of the graph, so you can just use the `get.edgelist()` to retrieve all direct connections in the graph object, which is a matrix:

```
library(igraph); library(dplyr);

edges <- get.edgelist(i96e)
edges

#         [,1]       [,2]       
#  [1,] "Alpha"    "Gasoline" 
#  [2,] "Bravo"    "Egg"      
#  [3,] "Bravo"    "Hurricane"
#  [4,] "Colonel"  "Felix"    
#  [5,] "Colonel"  "Indigo"   
#  [6,] "Demo"     "Felix"    
#  [7,] "Demo"     "Gasoline" 
#  [8,] "Demo"     "Jab"      
#  [9,] "Felix"    "Hurricane"
# [10,] "Felix"    "Indigo"   
# [11,] "Gasoline" "Jab"
```

The edge list returns an edge only once for each edge, so if you want the first connection for all vertices, you can switch the from and to column and bind with the original edge matrix and this gives a more convenient first order connection data frame:

```
edgeDF <- rbind(edges, edges[,c(2,1)]) %>% 
          as.data.frame() %>% 
          setNames(c("NodeId", "FirstConnection"))

edgeDF %>% arrange(NodeId, FirstConnection)
#       NodeId FirstConnection
# 1      Alpha        Gasoline
# 2      Bravo             Egg
# 3      Bravo       Hurricane
# 4    Colonel           Felix
# 5    Colonel          Indigo
# 6       Demo           Felix
# 7       Demo        Gasoline
# 8       Demo             Jab
# 9        Egg           Bravo
# 10     Felix         Colonel
# 11     Felix            Demo
# 12     Felix       Hurricane
# 13     Felix          Indigo
# 14  Gasoline           Alpha
# 15  Gasoline            Demo
# 16  Gasoline             Jab
# 17 Hurricane           Bravo
# 18 Hurricane           Felix
# 19    Indigo         Colonel
# 20    Indigo           Felix
# 21       Jab            Demo
# 22       Jab        Gasoline
```

The second degree connection is the connection of your first degree connection except that the second degree connection shouldn't be the original node, so you can join the first degree data frame with itself and filter records where second degree connections are equal to the nodes themselves:

```
SecondCon <- setNames(edgeDF, c("FirstConnection", "SecondConnection")) %>% 
             full_join(edgeDF) %>% filter(NodeId != SecondConnection)

SecondCon %>% arrange(NodeId, FirstConnection, SecondConnection)
#    FirstConnection SecondConnection    NodeId
# 1         Gasoline             Demo     Alpha
# 2         Gasoline              Jab     Alpha
# 3        Hurricane            Felix     Bravo
# 4            Felix             Demo   Colonel
# 5            Felix        Hurricane   Colonel
# 6            Felix           Indigo   Colonel
# 7           Indigo            Felix   Colonel
# 8            Felix          Colonel      Demo
# 9            Felix        Hurricane      Demo
# 10           Felix           Indigo      Demo
# 11        Gasoline            Alpha      Demo
# 12        Gasoline              Jab      Demo
# 13             Jab         Gasoline      Demo
# 14           Bravo        Hurricane       Egg
# 15         Colonel           Indigo     Felix
# 16            Demo         Gasoline     Felix
# 17            Demo              Jab     Felix
# 18       Hurricane            Bravo     Felix
# 19          Indigo          Colonel     Felix
# 20            Demo            Felix  Gasoline
# 21            Demo              Jab  Gasoline
# 22             Jab             Demo  Gasoline
# 23           Bravo              Egg Hurricane
# 24           Felix          Colonel Hurricane
# 25           Felix             Demo Hurricane
# 26           Felix           Indigo Hurricane
# 27         Colonel            Felix    Indigo
# 28           Felix          Colonel    Indigo
# 29           Felix             Demo    Indigo
# 30           Felix        Hurricane    Indigo
# 31            Demo            Felix       Jab
# 32            Demo         Gasoline       Jab
# 33        Gasoline            Alpha       Jab
# 34        Gasoline             Demo       Jab
```

Comment: that is perfect, and a lot less code than what I thought it would be. Thanks for your help!